# Why is my function not running?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm making a page which contains a single circle and a button. Upon pressing the button I want the circle to change to a random color.

Why is my code not running correctly?

```js
$("#button").click(function() {

  $("#thing").css("background-color", function() {

    var color = "#";

    var hex = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"];

    while (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {

      color += hex[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];

    }

    alert(color);

    return color;

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="thing"></div>

<button id="button">Click to change colour</button>
```

Comment: Change `while` to `for`. A `while` loop expects a single condition.

Comment: Check your console for syntax errors.

Comment: error in syntax, replace while with for

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [tour]. You may also want to check [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask], and how to create a [mcve]. Post the code you have tried and the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a for loop here. not a while loop.

```
for( var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
     color += hex[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You did'nt even made a circle, and you introduced a new syntax for `while` loop congrats on that

¯_(ツ)_/¯

Well you can have the following code an see what you were doing wrong in there and you do not return anything from click event you set the `color` rather than returning from there

```js
$("#button").click(function() {

  $("#thing").css("background-color", function() {

    var color = "#";

    var hex = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"];
    var i = 0;
    while (i < 6) {

      color += hex[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
      i++
    }
    $(this).css('background-color', color);
    //return color;

  });

});
```

```css
#thing {
  color: #000;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="thing">
</div>

<button id="button">Click to change colour</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

A few errors with your code. Hope this helps

```js
$("#button").click(function() {
  $("#thing").css("background-color", function() {
    var color = "#";
    var hex = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"];

    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      color += hex[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }

    alert(color);
    return color;
  })
})
```

```css
#thing {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #ededed;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="thing"></div>

<button id="button">Click to change colour</button>
```

Comment: any reason for the down vote?

Comment: I didn't dv, but maybe because you just posted some code with no explanation of what you did.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp, could be. thanks. Will work on this part

Comment: this answer has nothing wrong, don't worry dude here comes the +1 **(⌐■_■)**

Answer (score 0):

`while` does not work as you anticipated. The syntax you have would work as `for`, but not `while`.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  color += hex[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
}
```

If you want to use `while` you can do the following:

```js
let i = 0; 
while(i < 6) {
  color += hex[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  i++;
}
```

However there is no need for a loop to create a number between 0 and 0x1000000.

```js
/** Creates a color between 
 * #000000 and #ffffff inclusive
 */     
function createRandomColor() {
  const strHex = 
    Math.floor(Math.random() * 0x1000000)
    .toString(16)
    .padStart(6, '0');
  return `#${strHex}`;
}

const $thing = $('#thing');
$('#button').click(() => {
  $thing.css('background-color', createRandomColor());
});
```

```css
#thing {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #ededed;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="thing"></div>

<button id="button">Click to change colour</button>
```

I usually write ES6, but [`String.prototype.padStart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) is ES2017. If you follow to the doc you can fetch a polyfill.